# oAuth2 login on the api for web app in ruby on rails using doorkeeper with the help of devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, devise, oauth-2.0, doorkeeper

I am new to api development in Ruby On Rails. In the rails app I have devise for authenticating and I also want to use doorkeeper for OAuth2 login on the apis. I don't know how can I implement Api and how to use doorkeeper for that. Can anyone please explain it with the steps that I need to follow to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

To implement apis i personally like to use [grape](https://github.com/intridea/grape), by following the readme you will be up and running in no time :)

To integrate grape with doorkeeper instead you can either use [wine_bouncer](https://github.com/antek-drzewiecki/wine_bouncer), or [grape-doorkeeper](https://github.com/fuCtor/grape-doorkeeper).

Now depending on who consumes your api, doorkeeper comes with 4 [authorization grants](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Supported-Features), i quite recommend you to read the different grant types and their usage, you can read this [oauth2 simplified](https://aaronparecki.com/articles/2012/07/29/1/oauth2-simplified) article too.

To make doorkeeper to play along with devise you will need to modify your doorkeeper initializer as following:

The `resource_owner_authenticator` block is usually called when you do a authorization or implict grant request:

```
resource_owner_authenticator do |routes|
  # Put your resource owner authentication logic here.
  # If you want to use named routes from your app you need
  # to call them on routes object eg.
  # routes.new_user_session_path
  current_user || warden.authenticate!(:scope => :user)
end
```

You can check out the [example apps](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Example-Applications) at the doorkeeper wiki.

The password grant instead uses the `resource_owner_from_credentials` block and according to the wiki you can configure it as follow:

```
resource_owner_from_credentials do |routes|
  request.params[:user] = {:email => request.params[:username], :password => request.params[:password]}
  request.env["devise.allow_params_authentication"] = true
  request.env["warden"].authenticate!(:scope => :user)
end
```

Some resources that might help you :

- [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=api)
- [Building REST APIs with Rails](http://apionrails.icalialabs.com/book/)
- [surviving api](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/surviving-apis-with-rails)
  *[building api in a rails application](https://www.airpair.com/ruby-on-rails/posts/building-a-restful-api-in-a-rails-application)
- [grape in rails](http://funonrails.com/2014/03/building-restful-api-using-grape-in-rails/)

Hope it helps